# Android Databinding not working with RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-databinding, rx-java2

I use retrofit 2 + RxJava2 + Databinding library.

I want to update the progress bar visibility when performing an api call.

When the model is modified in onNext/onError/onCompleted callbacks the view is not updated. In onsubscribe it works. The code lines where I modify the model are executed. What might be the problem?

Model class + some helpers

```
public class RxUtils {
    public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> applyApiSchedulers() {
        return new ObservableTransformer<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<T> apply(@NonNull Observable<T> upstream) {
                return upstream.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            }
        };
    }

}

public class CompanyActivityModel extends BaseObservableModel {
        private boolean isLoading = false;
        private final ArrayList<Company> companies;

        public CompanyActivityModel() {
            this.companies = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Bindable
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }

        public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
            isLoading = loading;
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isVisible);
        }


        public ArrayList<Company> getCompanies() {
            return companies;
        }
    }

public class BaseObservableModel extends BaseObservable {
}
```

Progress bar Layout + Activity layout

```
    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="isVisible"
            type="boolean"/>

    </data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="@{isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type=".CompanyActivityModel"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_companies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <include
            app:isVisible = "@{model.loading}"
            layout="@layout/layout_progress_bar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

The api call

```
apiService.getAllCompanies(null)
                .compose(RxUtils.applyApiSchedulers())
                .subscribe(new Observer<GetAllCompaniesResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                        getModel().setLoading(true);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull GetAllCompaniesResponse getAllCompaniesResponse) {
                        if(!getAllCompaniesResponse.hasError()) {
                            companyDao.insertCompanies(getAllCompaniesResponse.getResult());
                        }
                        getModel().setLoading(false);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        getModel().setLoading(false);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        getModel().setLoading(false);
                        loadCompaniesFromDB();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isVisible);`

The BR value is generated based on the `@Bindable` annotation, not the name in the layout XML. So you're telling the data binding library that the wrong variable is getting updated.

`BR.loading` is probably the right value that should be provided.

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#observable_objects